# What was the release date of version 145.3 of the ExactTarget Web Service API?

Tags: api, soap-api, webservices, marketing-cloud

I need to know the release date of version 145.3 of the ExactTarget Web Service API?

Answer (score 1):

In 2013, we went to a month named release - you can get the up to date information for that [here](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/)

Release 145.3 was released July 13, 2012.